# Running DBT over SSH Tunnel and Jump Box

Tags: sql, ssh, ssh-tunnel, dbt

Is it possible to run DBT while connecting to a remote database through a Jump-Box?

I can get my SQL IDE's to work by providing the IP of the intermediary box and my SSH key, but I can't find anything in dbt's documentation which allows me to connect with SSH. I am looking for a solution outside of their cloud product so that I can run it locally and in our environment.

Comment: Hey Alex - this looks to me like it could be a common question. Could you expand on this (maybe include a how-to in your answer and sample profiles.yml) so that this could become a "pinned" question / answer?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is quite easy and I was over-complicating it.

First step is to port forward the 5432 port (if using PostgreSQL) from the jump box to your 5432. Then you should be able to put all the database connection credentials into the profiles.yml.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal, run below command for port forwarding to the local. And on the dbt `profiles.yml` update the connection as localhost

```bash
ssh -v -N -L 5432:$DB_IP:5432 $user@$JUMPER_IP
```